# Allow Zero DateTime mysql connector web.config Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

I'm getting a MySqlConnectionException when i'm trying to connect retrieve data from my DBContext class because i have a date time entry line `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

From what i understand i have to add a `Allow Zero Datetime=true` entry in my connection string, the one bellow.

```
<add name="A4LifeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/A4LifeEntities.csdl|res://*/A4LifeEntities.ssdl|res://*/A4LifeEntities.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;password=pass;user id=userId;port=3330;Allow Zero Datetime=true; persist security info=True;database=aLife&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/></connectionStrings>
```

As you can see i have already added it, but am i doing something wrong ? Do i have to add it somewhere else in the string ? Because it's not working.

Thank you

Comment: See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c9c06fe1-2ec3-4fda-8d15-55e801d96cf3/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Convert Zero Datetime=true;`, it's different in that it returns DateTime.MinValue instead of a MySqlDateTime.

Comment: Hey. When I add this to my connection string, it gives an error like 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0' Here is my conn string: "<add name="xyzEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/xyz.csdl|res://*/xyz.ssdl|res://*/xyz.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=xyz&quot;Convert Zero Datetime=true;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  />" What should I do?

Comment: @BurakKarakuş "Convert Zero Datetime=true;" should be after "database=xyz;" not after "&quot;"

Comment: `id=root;database=xyz&quot;Convert Zero Datetime=true;`
should be:
`id=root;database=xyz&quot;;Convert Zero Datetime=true;`
Because &quot; consumes one ; and then there is no commandseparation anymore